# Representing sales data using Neo4j

Tags: database, database-design, graph, neo4j

Has anyone ever tried to store sales data in graph database (Neo4J)?

Say product XX, 2000 copies was sold in US in 2016 and 1000 copies sold in UK in 2016. I have sales information for multiple products, in different years, in different countries. I also have sales information also for competitor products.

My problem is this: Sales of a product is specific for a specific country and year. I cannot just connect a product and sales. Would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in these cases you create additional node labels for nodes with this specific use.

For example, maybe a model like this:

```
(:ProductSale{name:'XX', saleYear:2016, amount:2000})-[:SOLD_TO]->(:Country{name:'USA'})
(:Product{name:'XX', description:'foo'})<-[:SALE_OF]-(:ProductSale)
```

That assumes you have data you want to save for each type of product. If not, you can get rid of the :Product node.